# copy/ install wkhtmltoimage on heroku from heroku bash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, wkhtmltoimage, ruby-on-rails-4.1

i am using `wkhtmltoimage` for my app.While deploying it to heroku it shows `wkhtmltoimage` executable not found in `/usr/local/bin` means that i have to install or copy executable to the heroku 's local/bin folder how can i install or copy from heroku bash to /usr/local/bin folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku does not play nicely with the IMGKit gem, and in order to make the screenshots work you need to download a compiled version of IMGKit.

```
https://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltoimage-0.10.0_rc2-static-amd64.tar.bz2
```

You unzipped it and put it in the ‘bin’ directory of the application. Then make a configure file for IMGKit so that this would actually take effect.

```
IMGKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltoimage = Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltoimage-amd64').to_s if ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'production'
end
```